# Driver error, Audio video and Touchpad do not work

Tags: 12.04, drivers, sound, wine, touchpad

I have a new device Dell 3537 with AMD radeon graphics. I tried to install wine on my device, since I am not very good at using Terminal, I probably messed up with things there so now the touchpad and the audio don't work. Also I can only get appearence of UBUNTU2D and cant get UBUNTU (3D), i.e, the windows don't resize when dragged on to the side or top of the windows. The the touchpad however works with

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

but only for a session also the scroll functionality of touchpad don't work with this as well, however the USB mouse works fine all the time.
How do I restore my device back to the stage where it worked fine?

Answer (score 0):

of course the fastest solution could be reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: But I don't want to reinstall but to recover. Furthermore I wish to learn to get the trouble solved through process.